# How do I fix pixelated fluid?

Tags: fluid-simulation, reflection

I'm making a water sim and I noticed when I rendered a frame that some of the water reflected the light weirdly, like a square or polygon.

The fluid closest to the camera also looks square-ish. How can I fix this and make it smoother?

[.blend file] https://pasteall.org/blend/19c9ec28feac4a66b8cd4d5c3370761c

[image]

Comment: Increase your resolution of the fluid simulation.  Smooth modifier is available.  Of course increasing the resolution of the fluid simulation increase memory and compute requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going into object and pressing shade smooth seemed to fix it while on the inflow object.